# What's the best way to get device locale in react native (iOS)?

Tags: react-native

Something similar to [NSLocale currentLocale] in Objective-C.

Answer (score 102):

There's no need for an external library. You can find what you're looking for in React's [Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios)

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'

// iOS:
const locale = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
               NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0] // "fr_FR"

// Android:
const locale = NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier // "fr_FR"
```

To test this, I changed the language on my device to French. Here's a sample of what you'll find in the `NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings` object related to locale:

```
{
    ...
    AppleKeyboards: [
        "fr_FR@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
        "en_US@sw=QWERTY;hw=Automatic",
        "es_419@sw=QWERTY-Spanish;hw=Automatic",
        "emoji@sw=Emoji"
    ]
    AppleLanguages: ["fr-US", "en-US", "es-US", "en"]
    AppleLanguagesDidMigrate: "9.2"
    AppleLocale: "fr_FR"
    NSLanguages: ["fr-US", "en-US", "es-US", "en"]
    ...
}
```

Comment: @DanielSteigerwald Accessing settings in this way is not yet supported on Android. See [Settings.android.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/94666f16c7da37e649316d40ea23d7a8054a04f9/Libraries/Settings/Settings.android.js)

Comment: Use `NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier` for Android

Comment: @evan_schmevan In ios NativeModules.SettingsManager is undefined and NativeModules is an empty object... :( ! Do you know what can be the reason?

Comment: @AralRoca are you using Expo by chance? It looks like it's an empty object when testing on Expo, but everything works as expected on an iOS simulator and real device.

Comment: I use this technique with Expo 33.0.0 and it works great, even when testing on Expo.

Comment: This appears to break on iOS13, when the native app built with the iOS13 SDK.

Comment: @TomSwift It seems like this is only the case on the simulator. It works fine on my iOS 13 device.

Comment: If `NativeModules.SettingsManager` is `null`, you also need to link the `react-native/RCTSettings` library by either adding `RCTSettings` to your Podfile and re-running `pod install`, or manually by following the guide here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html

Comment: As of ios 14, both `AppleLocale` and `AppleLanguages` seem to be defined. Would recommend picking `AppleLanguages` first now, since that supports the app specific prefered languages feature. and use optional chaining to better allow for backward compatibility

Answer (score 78):

```
import { Platform, NativeModules } from 'react-native'

const deviceLanguage =
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
          NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0] //iOS 13
        : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;

console.log(deviceLanguage); //en_US
```

Comment: As of iOS 13 AppleLocale no longer appears to be defined.  Anyone have a workaround for iOS 13?

Comment: @user3866793 `NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages` contains an array of languages, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58063292

Comment: As of ios 14, both `AppleLocale` and `AppleLanguages` seem to be defined. Would recommend picking `AppleLanguages` first now, since that supports the app specific prefered languages feature. and use optional chaining to better allow for backward compatibility

Answer (score 14):

I am using the i18n package (react-native-i18n).
And then it's just:

```
I18n = require('react-native-i18n')
locale = I18n.currentLocale()
```

Comment: Errors on newer versions of react FYI anyone.

Comment: This package is deprecated. You could use `react-native-localize` using `getCountry()` instead. It just returns the country without the language, ike this: `FR`

Answer (score 8):

Nothing of the above worked for me, but [this](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) component.

```
console.log("Device Locale", DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale()); // e.g en-US
```

Comment: Very nice package, but currently not maintained anymore -  the author is looking for someone to take over (at the time I'm posting this). Fingers crossed somebody will pick it up.

Comment: the react community picked it https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info

Comment: And removed getDeviceLocale() (https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-beta1) to "remove API duplication in the react-native-community modules"; use https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-localize

Answer (score 5):

```
function getLocale() {
  if (React.Platform.OS === 'android') {
    return I18n.locale;
  } else {
    return NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale.replace(/_/, '-');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

iOS 13 workaround here:

```js
locale = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale // "fr_FR"
console.log(" ==> Current settings: ", NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings)
if (locale === undefined) {
    // iOS 13 workaround, take first of AppleLanguages array 
    locale = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]
    if (locale == undefined) {
          return "en" // default language
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install [`react-native-i18n`](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n) and use this function:

```
import React, { NativeModules } from 'react-native'
...
function getLocale () {
  if (React.Platform.OS === 'android') {
    return NativeModules.RNI18n.getCurrentLocale(locale => locale.replace(/_/, '-'))
  } else {
    return NativeModules.RNI18n.locale.replace(/_/, '-')
  }
}
```

Works both under Android and iOS.

Comment: `NativeModules` does not have `RNI18n` (at least by default). I guess you added a lib.

Comment: There's no such thing as `getCurrentLocale` in that library though.

Answer (score 1):

This code is future proof

```typescript
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

function getSystemLocale(): string {
  let locale: string;
  // iOS
  if (
    NativeModules.SettingsManager &&
    NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings &&
    NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages
  ) {
    locale = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0];
    // Android
  } else if (NativeModules.I18nManager) {
    locale = NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;
  }

  if (typeof locale === 'undefined') {
    console.log('Couldnt get locale');
    return 'en';
  }

  return locale;
}

export default {
  getSystemLocale,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ npm install --save react-native-localize
```

--- or ---

```
$ yarn add react-native-localize
```

---

```
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";

console.log(RNLocalize.getLocales());

let defaultLanguage = RNLocalize.getLocales()[0].languageCode;

console.log('defaultLanguage', defaultLanguage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to extend react native yourself to get this info. But, depending on your use case, this localization component ([stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization)) may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for Android and iOS (RN 0.35)

```
import React, {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

if (NativeModules.I18nManager) {
    const {localeIdentifier, isRTL} = NativeModules.I18nManager;
}
```

May be this will help to someone, but iOS not shows locale property. It shows only rtl support now.

Answer (score 0):

if you develop over Expo... you can use:

`console.log(await NativeModules.ExponentUtil.getCurrentLocaleAsync());`
`console.log(await NativeModules.ExponentUtil.getCurrentDeviceCountryAsync());`
`console.log(await NativeModules.ExponentUtil.getCurrentTimeZoneAsync());`

Answer (score 0):

NativeModules solution [can be changed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10709) over time by Facebook developers.
Because of this reason I had prepared [a component](https://github.com/efkan/react-native-system-settings). (It works only on Android for now)

Sample usage:

```
import SystemSettings from 'react-native-system-settings'

SystemSettings.get(
    settings => console.log('settings: ', settings)
)
```

Also promise-then can be used:

```
SystemSettings.get().then(settings => console.log('settings: ', settings)).done()
```

Also ES7 async-await method can be used!

```
class App extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this._loadInitialState()
    }

    _loadInitialState = async () => {
        try {
            let settings = await SystemSettings.get()
            // Now settings variable would be filled and can be used!
        } catch (error) {}
    };
}
```

A sample result:

```
{
    densityDpi: 320,
    fontScale: 1,
    hardKeyboardHidden: "no",
    keyboard: "qwerty",
    keyboardHidden: "no",
    localization: {
        country: "US",
        displayCountry: "United States",
        displayLanguage: "English",
        displayName: "English (United States)",
        is24HourFormat: false,
        language: "en",
        locale: "en_US",
        networkCountry: "US",
        simCountry: "US",
        timeZone: {
            ID: "Europe/Amsterdam",
            displayName: {
                long: "Amsterdam Standard Time",
                short: "GMT+01:00",
            },
            offset: 3600000
        }
    },
    orientation: "portrait",
    screenHeightDp: 615,
    screenLayout: "normal",
    screenWidthDp: 360,
    smallestScreenWidthDp: 360,
    uiModeType: "normal"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer use react-native-i18n.
then you can use like this inside the documentation..

```
import { getLanguages } from 'react-native-i18n'

getLanguages().then(languages => {
  console.log(languages) // ['en-US', 'en']
})
```

link: https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n

Comment: that package 'react-native-i18n' already deprecated please do not suggest:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

// Android

```
NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier
```

// iOS

```
NativeModules.SettingsManager?.settings?.AppleLocale || NativeModules.SettingsManager?.settings?.AppleLanguages[0]
```

package:

> import {
> NativeModules, Platform
> } from 'react-native';

Complete solution per platform where "lan" is the system language

```
const lan = Platform.select({
  ios: NativeModules.SettingsManager?.settings?.AppleLocale || NativeModules.SettingsManager?.settings?.AppleLanguages[0],
  android: NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using expo-localization library

```
import { getLocales } from "expo-localization";
```

Sample Output

```json
[
  {
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "currencySymbol": "$",
    "decimalSeparator": ".",
    "digitGroupingSeparator": ",",
    "languageCode": "en",
    "languageTag": "en-US",
    "measurementSystem": "us",
    "regionCode": "US",
    "textDirection": "ltr"
  },
  {
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "currencySymbol": "$",
    "decimalSeparator": ".",
    "digitGroupingSeparator": ",",
    "languageCode": "ru",
    "languageTag": "ru-US",
    "measurementSystem": "us",
    "regionCode": "US",
    "textDirection": "ltr"
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using [react-native-i18n](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n)

in order to access the device's language I used:

```
import { getLanguages } from 'react-native-i18n';

getLanguages().then(languages => {
  console.log(languages); // ['en-US', 'en']
});
```

It's all in the documentation.