# format numbers function works only when I do debbuging React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a function to format numbers which I use in my project in React Native

```
function formatedNumber(value){
  return value ? parseFloat(value).toLocaleString("pt-br", {minimumFractionDigits: 2 }) : "0.00"
}
```

and example of using

```
<Text style={{fontSize:16}}>Valor of the value: {obj.value!= null && <Text>{formatedNumber(obj.value)}</Text>}</Text>
```

The problem is that on it shows formatted value ( so instead 10000 shows 10.000,00) only when I am on debugging mode, otherwise the value stays unformatted.

Versions

"expo": "^33.0.0",

"react": "16.8.3",

"react-native": "0.61.2"

Comment: What do you mean by "only shows in debugging mode"? Are you able to see the `Text` component? or just the value

Comment: I m able to see Text Component but without formated value so like "Valor of the value:  1000" instead of "Valor of the value: 1.000,00 ". But when I start debbuing mode I can see that the code stop on formatedNumber func and the values appear formated on the screen

Comment: If you're using Android, this could be the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55861894

Comment: Answer here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19410