# toLocaleString() is not working in Android for React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, timestamp, datetime-format

I am trying to do some date format in my application.

Suppose I am getting date stamp like  `"1573457092953.63"`
And I am trying to do like below format.

```
"11/11/2019, 1:17:00"
```

So, I have used `date.toLocaleString()`

It is working fine in iOS, But, Getting issue in Android.

```
In iOS getting like 11/11/2019, 1:17:00 PM
Android getting like Mon Nov 11 1:17:00
```

How to fix this, Even I did not get anything from other forums.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to look at momentJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found finally some library called

> moment

```
"moment": "^2.24.0" // in package.json file

import Moment from 'moment';

Moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY, hh:mm:ss')
Output is 11/11/2019, 1:17:00
```

Hope this will help someone in future.

It is working fine for both iOS and Andorid domains.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `toLocaleString()` doesn't work on Android. Please, check the following [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15717).

The workaround is to create a custom mapping and to use it:

```
const dateTimeMapping = {
        en: {
            onlyTime: 'h:mm A',
            shortDate: 'ddd, D MMMM',
            longDate: 'D MMMM YYYY h:mm A',
        },
        de: {
            onlyTime: 'H:mm',
            shortDate: 'ddd, D. MMMM',
            longDate: 'LLL',
        },
        it: {
            onlyTime: 'H:mm',
            shortDate: 'ddd D MMMM',
            longDate: 'D MMMM YYYY HH:MM',
        },
 }
```

Pass the locale property and the type of the format:

```
const result = dateTimeMapping[locale][type];
```

About the number formatting, you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408025/react-native-tolocalestring-not-working-on-android).