# How to get current language setting in the phone with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would like my app to support multiple languages, for example English and Chinese. Using react native, how do I find the language settings on the phone?

Comment: This is a coding community, could you provide the coding problem you are facing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to get device locale in react native (iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468746/whats-the-best-way-to-get-device-locale-in-react-native-ios)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this library -> https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n

```
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';
deviceLocale = I18n.currentLocale()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I used the library(react-native-device-info) and solved it. this library has many informations about the device.      
[react-native-device-info](https://github.com/facebook/react-native)
      
`const DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
const currentLocale = DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale();`

Comment: The library is now deprecated and no longer maintained.

Answer (score 41):

```
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';

const deviceLanguage =
          Platform.OS === 'ios'
            ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
              NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0] // iOS 13
            : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;

console.log(deviceLanguage); //en_US
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: you can get the local without using any library.

Comment: More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35493069/2206455

Comment: sounds like the best option, without any use of third party components

Answer (score 3):

```js
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';

let deviceLanguage = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 
    NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale:
    NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;

if (deviceLanguage === undefined) {
    // iOS 13 workaround, take first of AppleLanguages array 
    deviceLanguage = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]
    if (deviceLanguage == undefined) {
        return defaultLocalization // default language
    }
}
```

Comment: defaultLocalization  is not declared

Answer (score 1):

```
export const getDeviceLanguage = () => {
  const locale = Platform.select({
    ios: () =>
      NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
      NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0],
    default: () => NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier,
  })();
  return locale.replace('-', '_').split('_')[0];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-localize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-localize) and get current user's device language:

```
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";

console.log(RNLocalize.getLocales());
```